# Connecting to an online SQL database

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, cpanel

To whom it may concern,

A friend of mine has a server with a database which he created for me.

I wish to connect to this database with my Java app,
For now I got this code:

```
    /**
     * Open database connection
     */
    public void openConnection() {
        try {
            //  Database information
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://url-to-online-database.com:3306/";
            String dbName = "dbName";

            //  jdbc driver
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            //  username of database user
            String userName = "testUsername";
            //  Password of database user
            String password = "testPassword";

            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

            //  Adding multiple exception catches
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
    }
```

At this point I don't know what I am doing wrong besides the fact I don't know where to obtain the url to use to connect to this database.

When trying to log in, in my app, I get the following errors:
[image: class not found]

[image: nullpointerexception]

Is this related to remote mysql? Do I need to "Add Access Host" in cpanel?
Maybe duplicate JARs that are using my driver?

Comment: "besides the fact I don't know what url to use to connect to this database" does this mean you *don't* know the URL and are confused as to why you can't connect? ><

Comment: I don't know the URL, and I don't know where to obtain it :P

Comment: most of the set up for getting connected would be on your friend's server, not on your end.  Ensure firewall rules are allowing connections, ensure connections are allowed from the db end, make sure there's a user set up for you, obtain the IP address/port number and/or domain the server is hosted on.  Lots to do on your friend's side before you'd be able to connect

Comment: There is a user set, which is connected to the database I am using.

Answer (score 0):

As in your question there is no such drviver found for java mysql connectivity so please add mysql-java-connector in your project library and run.

[Download MySQL Java Connector](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar.zip)

Comment: Using that will result in an error while logging in from my app: Communications link failure, The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server

Comment: make sure your mysql server is running also make sure your server has max connection limit allow to access database. One more thing are you trying to access mysql server globally or locally?

Comment: It's url to which I need to connect. What do I use? Is it the 'main domain' url?

Comment: I mean your mysql server is on same place where your java app ?

Comment: No, it's in a different location

Comment: Okay, then first of all you need to allow access of database from any ip, then you can access any database globally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67326/discussion-between-miya-g-and-mr-goose).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a maven project. If you use maven you need to add a dependency for mysql-connector like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your database in other location ,your program can not find this url because ,you try to connect to remote database ,you need to create adHoc network and share your dataBase.